# How to force Maven to use git-describe suffix for snapshot version during install

Tags: java, git, maven

I have third party `Java` project which uses `Maven` to build.

The project has specified `1.0-SNAPSHOT` as version in `pom.xml` file.

```
...  
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
...
```

I'd like to build project on private build server and install resulting `jar` into private maven repository.

Currently when project is installed or deployed via `mvn install` or `mvn deploy` the resulting artifact has suffixed with timestamp like this `artifact-name-1.0-20200320.102713-1.jar`.
Such version is rather uninformative.

I'd like to have version suffix to include `git describe` instead of timestamp.

Is there a way to customize suffix to include more information like git commit id?

Answer (score 1):

The situation is a bit different to what you probably think.

Maven has just one build in mechanism that does not treat a version number "verbatim", and this mechanism is `SNAPSHOT`. `SNAPSHOT` versions are stored in Nexus/Artifactory as time-stamped, numbered versions so that Nexus/Artifactory can always give you last version when you ask for `SNAPSHOT`. There is no way to alter that mechanism.

On the other hand, you can build non-Snapshot versions that depend on properties.

You can e.g. define a version `1.0.0-${revision}` and set the property `revision` through the command line.